# How does one get around the firebase hosting proof of ownership catch 22?

Tags: firebase-hosting

Firebase hosting requires that a `TXT` setting be set up to as they call it

> Prove the domain is yours

I purchased a domain.  It is mine.  In order to set this `TXT` setting I have to have the domain hosted.  The place I purchased the domain from sells hosting for minimum one year at a time.   What is the point of firebase hosting when I have to buy hosting somewhere in order to prove that the domain is mine?   Is there any way to get around this catch 22?

Answer (score 0):

Proving ownership is done by putting a [`TXT` record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TXT_record) in the DNS. This doesn't require that you have a website hosted yet, it merely requires access to the DNS settings for your domain.

It's hard to help beyond that without knowing where you registered your domain.

Comment: Purchased from a cheap domain dealer.  The setting for TXT record for the DNS is available only through the hosting plan panel.  Minimum time period to buy a hosting plan is one year.   $3 USD to buy the domain, $55 USD to buy the hosting plan.   I will just have to dump the domain and find another one.  Write it off as a loss.  I already created a website and logos for it.  Oh well:(   Lesson to be learned here: do not be fooled by cheap domains and think you will be able to host on firebase for free just like that.

Comment: Ouch... I'd indeed avoid any domain registrar that doesn't provide you a way to edit the DNS settings for your domain. But most registrars actually separate the two: allowing DNS zone edits with the registration, charging extra for hosting.

Comment: It turns out that TXT settings is the first of two steps firebase hosting requires.   The second part of the firebase hosting process is A settings.  I was going to buy a new different domain from a different dealer and start over.  The new dealer offered month to month hosting.   One month $12, ok fine.  Chump change.  No cigar!   firebase free hosting wants you to maintain your A settings with the domain/hosting provider.

Comment: Frank suggests making sure the zone edits and hosting are not separate services.   Good advice only these dealers do not make details of what is or is not bundled into their domain and hosting products clearly apparent or easy to find information.

Comment: I've personally only dealt with Gandi.net and Google Domains, and helped developers with GoDaddy and namecheap, and all of those allow you to edit the DNS of your domain without requiring an additional hosting package. I'm quite sure *many* other registrars do the same. I'd search for a registrar with good reviews and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Update.  I took Frank's advice and set up a few Namecheap accounts.  Wowie!   The discount names are as cheap as 50 cents/year if you buy 1 or 5 years.   Thanx for the advice.   There is a caveat to using Namecheap/firebase, however.

Do not take this as if I were looking a gift horse in the mouth.   I am super grateful to Google for free hosting.  I merely want to warn users that firebase is not a free country.  Google forces the s religion.   I put in many hours of work to create my website using my girlfriend's hosting MySQL.  Her hosting platform does not have an s in the URL: https.   So the Angular 5 HTTP calls barf.   I also included a contact page and a share via email popup.   I used my girlfriend's hosting and set up a poor man's PHP web service for that.   That does not work because girlfriend's hosting uses HTTP not https.   So now I have to go back and recode these backend connections to use Google firebase and Google functions/SendGrid.  I could have done that from the get-go and saved myself the time and aggravation.

Comment: Update.   Sending emails from a contact page barfs because firebase forces https connections and disables http connections.  The workaround: Google functions which call SendGrid is turning out to be a security nightmare.  Many videos and tutorials regarding how to set it up are useless.  The problem is the responses are being mangled with some craziness called CORS.  This too is a recently added security impediment.   So far my search for a solution has found many people in the same predicament with no clear answers regarding how to fix the problem.

Comment: Update2.  What appears to be a CORS security error message is misleading.  The problem has nothing to do with security.   The problem is with firebase pricing.  The free plan does not allow outbound networking for google functions.    After further research I realized that using cloud functions with SendGrid is not the right solution for a contact form.  I saw a stackoverflow post on the topic of using gmail to do this.   See "Implementing sending email with Firebase cloud functions".